# Particle Information in Wave State

Tags: particle-physics, waves, quantum-information, information

I'm not formerly trained in physics and am more of an "enthusiast". That said, I was wondering if particles in their "wave state" contain/carry information. If the answer is yes, then does that mean that information can be carried by a particle without a physically known location/existence?
Thanks to all,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particles do not have a "wave state", so to speak. We refer to this concept of particles having wavelike behavior as the [wave-particle duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality), and in the context of the location of the particle, quantum mechanics tells us that the wavelike nature of the particle is expressed in the particles [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function).

When considering the wavelike nature of something that also exhibits particle behavior, we take the shape of the wave to be a [wave packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet), and we say that the particle is "spread out" or "smeared" over the extent of the wave packet. This means that the particle doesn't have a definite location - making multiple measurements on the location of a particle may yield different results. The distribution of measurement results will be related to the wave function and have variances in accordance with the [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle). If you take a look at the left graphs in [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality#/media/File:Quantum_mechanics_travelling_wavefunctions_wavelength.svg) you may find a better way to intuitively relate the value of the wave function to the probability of finding a particle in a given region.

Comment: Thanks so much Billy. 
Before probability wave collapses, wave-particle duality, does that probably particle carry/contain information?
Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure! If my answer helped you, it would be really helpful to me if you could accept it as an answer. As for your second question, it depends what you consider "information". Is the location of the particle not information? Any measureable property of the particle can be considered information; how this information is interpreted depends on the system the particle is travelling in.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting at... I don't believe that the conscious exists in the brain, necessarily. There seems to be an argument that consciousness is a byproduct of brain activity; that there needs to be a physical component to it. However, if a particle that isn't in a "physical" form can contain information, then...